# jquery datepicker: Multiple instances with different settings

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to have two datepicker instances on the same page, but they need to function with different settings, specifically, I need 'datepicker A' to show full date calendar on click, but I need 'datepicker B' to NOT show the date calendar on click because 'datepicker B' is set up to only show Month/Year.

By playing around a bit, I found that I can addClass beforeShow (a CSS class) on 'datepicker B' so that it does NOT display the calendar (display:none). But this created a new problem in which the following would happen:

1. Click on datepicker A and full calendar shows (sweet!).
2. Click on datepicker B and NO calendar shows (yeah, baby!).
3. Click on datepicker A again... and full calendar does NOT show anymore... (huh?).

So, I played around a bit more and realized that I could simply do the opposite on 'datepicker A', removeClass beforeShow to ensure that full calendar still shows, even after having clicked on the other datepicker. And this seems to be working pretty good.

But, I have a feeling there should be a better way to do this? Why do I have to be adding/removing a class between datepickers just to keep them working on different settings? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Here's a fiddle example and the code I'm using for my 'hacky' solution: http://jsfiddle.net/sergeidave/xt9vsjnq/

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <label>Date with Calendar:</label>
    <input id="datepicker" name="datepicker" type="text"/>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Month-Year Only:</label>
    <input id="monthpicker" name="monthpicker" type="text"/>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        beforeShow: function (e, t) {
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").removeClass("hide-calendar");                    
        },
    });
    $( "#monthpicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        beforeShow: function (e, t) {
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("hide-calendar");                    
        },
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.hide-calendar .ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Yup. I can elaborate. The ID is being assigned in the .js file. Let me explain with an answer.

Comment: Sounds like datepicker B doesn't require a real datepicker and jQuery UI's datepicker is overkill for what could be replaced with a pair of simple month and year selects.

Comment: @NicholasHazel did you have a chance to write up an answer? Thanks!